# How to extract JSON from a nested JSON file?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am calling an API and getting a response like the below.

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "errmsg": "OK",
    "data": {
        "total": 12,
        "items": [{
                "id": 11,
                "name": "BBC",
                "priority": 4,
                "levelStr": "All",
                "escalatingChainId": 3,
                "escalatingChain": {
                    "inAlerting": false,
                    "throttlingAlerts": 20,
                    "enableThrottling": true,
                    "name": "Example123",
                    "destination": [],
                    "description": "",
                    "ccdestination": [],
                    "id": 3,
                    "throttlingPeriod": 10
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "name": "CNBC",
                "priority": 4,
                "levelStr": "All",
                "escalatingChainId": 3,
                "escalatingChain": {
                    "inAlerting": false,
                    "throttlingAlerts": 20,
                    "enableThrottling": true,
                    "name": "Example456",
                    "destination": [],
                    "description": "",
                    "ccdestination": [],
                    "id": 3,
                    "throttlingPeriod": 10
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to clean-up this JSON a bit and produce a simple JSON like below where `escalatingChainName` is the `name` in the `escalatingChain` list so that I can write this into a CSV file.

```
{
    "items": [{
            "id": 11,
            "name": "BBC",
            "priority": 4,
            "levelStr": "All",
            "escalatingChainId": 3,
            "escalatingChainName": "Example123"
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "name": "CNBC",
            "priority": 4,
            "levelStr": "All",
            "escalatingChainId": 3,
            "escalatingChainName": "Example456"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a JSON function that I can use to copy only the necessary key-value or nested key-values to a new JSON object?

With the below code, I am able to get the details list.

```
json_response = response.json()
items = json_response['data']
details = items['items']
```

I can print individual list items using

```
for x in details:
    print(x)
```

How do I take it from here to pull only the necessary fields like id, name, priority and the name from `escalatingchain` to create a new list or JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no existing function that will do what you want, so you'll need to write one. Fortunately that's not too hard in this case — basically you just create a list of new items by extracting the pieces of data you want from the existing ones.

```
import json

json_response = """\
    {
        "status": 200,
        "errmsg": "OK",
        "data": {
            "total": 12,
            "items": [{
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "BBC",
                    "priority": 4,
                    "levelStr": "All",
                    "escalatingChainId": 3,
                    "escalatingChain": {
                        "inAlerting": false,
                        "throttlingAlerts": 20,
                        "enableThrottling": true,
                        "name": "Example123",
                        "destination": [],
                        "description": "",
                        "ccdestination": [],
                        "id": 3,
                        "throttlingPeriod": 10
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "name": "CNBC",
                    "priority": 4,
                    "levelStr": "All",
                    "escalatingChainId": 3,
                    "escalatingChain": {
                        "inAlerting": false,
                        "throttlingAlerts": 20,
                        "enableThrottling": true,
                        "name": "Example456",
                        "destination": [],
                        "description": "",
                        "ccdestination": [],
                        "id": 3,
                        "throttlingPeriod": 10
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
"""


response = json.loads(json_response)

cleaned = []
for item in response['data']['items']:
    cleaned.append({'id': item['id'],
                    'name': item['name'],
                    'priority': item['priority'],
                    'levelStr': item['levelStr'],
                    'escalatingChainId': item['escalatingChainId'],
                    'escalatingChainName': item['escalatingChain']['name']})

print('cleaned:')
print(json.dumps(cleaned, indent=4))
```

Comment: Thank you !! This works perfectly for what I am looking for. Appending to the list in a loop makes much more sense and how to get those values.

Comment: If you were going to be copying a much larger number of fields, it might be worth writing a utility function that did the work given only a list of keys to reduce the amount of repetitive code required, but for a relatively small number like this, it's best to just spell them out individually and move on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
data = {
    "status": 200,
    "errmsg": "OK",
    "data": {
        "total": 12,
        "items": [{
                "id": 11,
                "name": "BBC",
                "priority": 4,
                "levelStr": "All",
                "escalatingChainId": 3,
                "escalatingChain": {
                    "inAlerting": False,
                    "throttlingAlerts": 20,
                    "enableThrottling": True,
                    "name": "Example123",
                    "destination": [],
                    "description": "",
                    "ccdestination": [],
                    "id": 3,
                    "throttlingPeriod": 10
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "name": "CNBC",
                "priority": 4,
                "levelStr": "All",
                "escalatingChainId": 3,
                "escalatingChain": {
                    "inAlerting": False,
                    "throttlingAlerts": 20,
                    "enableThrottling": True,
                    "name": "Example456",
                    "destination": [],
                    "description": "",
                    "ccdestination": [],
                    "id": 3,
                    "throttlingPeriod": 10
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

for single_item in data["data"]["items"]:
    print(single_item["id"])
    print(single_item["name"])
    print(single_item["priority"])
    print(single_item["levelStr"])
    print(single_item["escalatingChain"]["inAlerting"])
    # and so on
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I create a JSON from the print statements in your response?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of approaching this depending on whether your dealing with a variable or `.json` file using python list and dictionary comprehension:

1. Where data variable of type dictionary (nested) already defined:

   ```py
   # keys you want
   to_keep = ['id', 'name', 'priority', 'levelStr', 'escalatingChainId',
              'escalatingChainName']
   new_data = [{k:v for k,v in low_dict.items() if k in to_keep}
               for low_dict in data['data']['items']]
   # where item is dictionary at lowest level
   escalations = [{v+'Name':k[v]['name']} for k in data['data']['items']
                                           for v in k if type(k[v])==dict]
   # merge both lists of python dictionaries to produce flattened list of dictionaries
   new_data = [{**new,**escl} for new,escl in zip(new_data,escalations)]
   ```
2. Or (and since your refer `json` package) if you have save the response to as a `.json` file:

   ```py
   import json

   with open('response.json', 'r') as handl:
       data = json.load(handl)
   to_keep = ['id', 'name', 'priority', 'levelStr', 'escalatingChainId',
              'escalatingChainName']
   new_data = [{k:v for k,v in low_dict.items() if k in to_keep}
                        for low_dict in data['data']['items']]
   escalations = [{v+'Name':k[v]['name']} for k in data['data']['items']
                                            for v in k if type(k[v])==dict]
   new_data = [{**new,**escl} for new,escl in zip(new_data,escalations)]
   ```

Both produce output:

```
[{'id': 11,
  'name': 'BBC',
  'priority': 4,
  'levelStr': 'All',
  'escalatingChainId': 3,
  'escalatingChainName': 'Example123'},
 {'id': 21,
  'name': 'CNBC',
  'priority': 4,
  'levelStr': 'All',
  'escalatingChainId': 3,
  'escalatingChainName': 'Example456'}]
```

Comment: Thank you !! This is getting more closer to the expected output. is there a way to bring the nested list of  "escalatingChain": {name: Example123} in the original json as a new key in the output with the other values?

Comment: great point -- have now added code for this.

Comment: Works brilliantly now !! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

There is an even better way to do it, by using a [`generator`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generators-in-python/) like this:-

```
def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for k, v in json_input.items():
            if k == lookup_key:
                yield v
            else:
                yield from item_generator(v, lookup_key)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)
```

This will invoke a recursive call and give you the value of key you desire even if there are lists in between the code. Just call it with a function like this:-

```
    for j in item_generator(p_d, i):
        {}


print(output)
```